# What Would Our Design For the Site Be?

Tags: discussion, design

As we approach Public Beta and possibly graduation, we should think ahead for the future for this site. A lot of graduated sites have cool features, like different badge logos and backgrounds. Let's start thinking about what we'd like our site to look like: please answer this question with ideas about stuff like badge icons, downvote/upvote buttons, color themes, even the background! All ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The site does not get a design until it is about to graduate. As things currently stand with the SE site-graduation process, this will not happen for *years*.

Yes, I know that the "The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta" thing linked above claims that "What should our logo and site design look like?" is an essential question. [That is a baldfaced lie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201776/224428) (at least, it is today; it made more sense in the early days of Area 51). Ignore it. No good comes of reading that blogpost.

Do not bother devoting any energy to the question of what the site design should look like at this point in time. Learn to love the generic beta site design. You'll be seeing a lot of it.